# Value adjusted in multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

When I update the balance of certain record in the array, using the deposit and withdraw amounts, the balance for that sepcific record changes along with the balance for the records in arrays.

How to fix it?

```
private String name;
private int pin;
private int account;
private static double balance;
```

---

```
public void setBalance(double amount)
{
    balance = amount;
}

public static void deposit(double aDeposit) 
{ 
balance = balance + aDeposit; 
} 
public static void withdraw(double aWithdraw) 
{ 
    if  
    ( balance >= aWithdraw) 
        balance = balance - aWithdraw; 
    else if 
    ( balance < aWithdraw) 
        System.out.println("Cannot withdarw amount."); 
}

public double getBalance( )
{
    return balance;
}
public boolean equal(CustomerRecord otherObject)
{
    return (name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherObject.name) &&
           (pin == otherObject.pin) &&
           (account == otherObject.account) &&
           (balance == otherObject.balance));

      }
  }
```

---

```
    do{   


        System.out.println("Enter the name");
        String aName;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        aName = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the pin");
        int aPin;
        aPin = keyboard.nextInt();


             for

             (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
              CustomerRecord record = anotherArray[i];
              if
              ((record.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aName)) && (record.getPin() == (aPin)))

          {
                 System.out.println(record);

             System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to Deposit");
             double aDeposit;
             aDeposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
             CustomerRecord.deposit(aDeposit);

             System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to withdraw");
             double aWithdraw;
             aWithdraw = keyboard.nextDouble();
             CustomerRecord.withdraw(aWithdraw);


            record.getBalance();

  }
             }

        System.out.println("\nAnother Transaction? (y for yes) (n for no)");
        repeat = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    }
    while
        (

         repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y') ;

        //Print the records on screen

    { for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        System.out.print(anotherArray[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown where you define the `balance` field but going by the fact that you are able to access it from a `static` methods `deposit` and `withdraw` I would guess it is itself a static variable, say

```
private static double balance;
```

Now, what does the `static` mean here? If you figure that out, you will know what is the error in your program, and why changing it in one object changes it in all

Comment: Okay, I've shown you how I defined my variables. what does static mean?

Comment: So it *is* `static`. That's not surprising. What does it mean for a `field` to be `static`?

Comment: Any idea, how to just display a single record from an array? to display the balance after the deposit & withdraw and before asking the user for any other transactions?

Comment: Glad you figured it. And thank you for using homework tag, hopefully I answered within the guidelines of giving pointers without giving actual answer.

Comment: Haha, it was perfect! Just a small doubt, if you could help me in that.